# How to remove wobble effect in my HTML5 canvas mousepan method?

Tags: javascript, navigation, html5-canvas

I'm working on a tile based game project that uses a massive HTML5 canvas to render the board.

Currently I am ironing out bugs to create the best possible user experience and currently my mousepan script is creating an unfortunate wobble effect when detecting when to switch direction. Please find the code below, any ways of softening out the effect (which is being caused by the harsh threshold of (`e.pageX >= oldx`) would be fantastic. All in pursuit of a smooth canvas mousepan script!

```
if (e.pageX >= oldx) {
scroll.x -= (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / 45;

if (scroll.y < 0) {
    scroll.y = 0;
};

if (scroll.x < 0) {
    scroll.x = 0;
};

} else {

scroll.x += (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / 45;

if (scroll.y < 0) {
    scroll.y = 0;
};

if (scroll.x < 0) {
    scroll.x = 0;
};

}

if (e.pageY >= oldy) {
scroll.y -= (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / 45;

if (scroll.y < 0) {
    scroll.y = 0;
};

if (scroll.x < 0) {
    scroll.x = 0;
};

} else {

scroll.y += (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / 45;

if (scroll.y < 0) {
    scroll.y = 0;
};

if (scroll.x < 0) {
    scroll.x = 0;
};

}

oldx = e.pageX;
oldy = e.pageY;
```

Comment: can you post your animation loop?

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what you mean by wobble effect. I can only guess, but try rounding your coordinate values. `Math.round((e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / 45)`